# Which one is correct in examples?

Tags: tense, american-english

I have some confusion about the following sentence.

1. It was broken, but it's OK. Now it (has been repaired).
2. It was broken, but it's OK. Now it (is being repaired).
3. It was broken, but it's OK. Now it (was repaired).

Which one is correct sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence sounds OK. The action started in the past and finished in the present.

I think the second sentence seems wrong. How come it is OK now when it is being repaired? It should be rewritten as "It was broken, but it'll be OK". (It's being repaired).

The third sentence also sounds OK.

Comment: I think it sounds weird to combine "now" with "was" in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

First sentence is correct. It indicates that the thing was broken previously and in present it has been repaired.

> It was broken, but it's OK. Now it (has been repaired).

or may be written as

> It was broken, but now it's OK. It (has been repaired).